# Problems to deploy latest version via Java installer and Tomcat8 inside OSGeoLive 13 VM

Tags: java, error, geonetwork, deployment

For a presentation of Geonetwork in our group I wanted to have the latest version of GN (v3.10.2) instead of the one implemented in the VM (3.2.1?) that was working flawlessly. (Awesome work to be sure!)

However, I was neither able to make it fly with the Java installer and a deployment in my users home directory, nor via Tomcat8 and the respective war file.

As the title suggests I am inside a OSGeoLive 13 VM with Ubuntu 18.04, Tomcat 8 etc.

`$ java -version` gives:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_242" OpenJDK Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08) OpenJDK
>   64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)

First I made sure, that the original instance of GN is not running. Then I tried starting the new one installed via java installer from the Lubuntu menu, the CPU meter goes up for a while, goes flat again, but nothing happens - no GN on the expected URL and Port.

Errors from …jetty/logs/geonetwork.log:

> 2020-04-08 14:19:16,267 ERROR [jeeves] - JeevesContextLoaderListener:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/home/user/geonetwork/web/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/domain-3.10.2-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean
>   property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
>   [file:/home/user/geonetwork/web/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Locked by
>   another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s);
>   use the server mode [90020-174])
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/home/user/geonetwork/web/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/domain-3.10.2-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean
>   property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL
>   [file:/home/user/geonetwork/web/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Database may be already in use: "Locked by
>   another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s);
>   use the server mode [90020-174])
>   …

I googled hours for it, but all I found in the end was related to H2 db issues on tomcat deployments.

So, why not checking this out instead - booyaah!! download → put in tomcat webapps folder → changed permissions → started tomcat via systemctl → "succesful!" ??? - Nope, I ran into another issue.

/var/log/tomcat8/geonetwork.log says:

> 2020-04-08 17:46:15,443 ERROR [jeeves] - JeevesContextLoaderListener:
>   null java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.io.File.(File.java:277)
>           at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(JeevesContextLoaderListener.java:60)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1852)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2020-04-08 17:46:15,461 FATAL [jeeves.engine] - Raised exception during init
>   2020-04-08 17:46:15,462 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Exception :
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 2020-04-08 17:46:15,462 FATAL
>   [jeeves.engine] -    Message   : null 2020-04-08 17:46:15,472 FATAL
>   [jeeves.engine] -    Stack     : java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.io.File.(File.java:277)
>           at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(JeevesContextLoaderListener.java:60)
>   …

No idea where to start - Java error message are always some sort of orcish to me.
Tried to fiddle around for quite a while, but now I am out of ideas here.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation solved the issues in the end.